# Switch images on hover in CSS

Tags: css, hover, css-grid

I have a grid created in CSS (of which only one of the items is shown in the code below)

**CSS:**
/* Grid 1 START*/

```
.grid-1 {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
grid-template-rows: auto quto auto;
grid-gap: 4px;
}
```

/* Grid 1 END*/

**Html:**

```
<div class="item-1"><a href="image#1/"><img class="alignleft wp-image-5497 size-full" src="image#1.png" alt="" width="300" height="200" /></a></div>
```

If on hovering the mouse over the image#1, I need to replace the image#1 (on hover only) to image#2 what would the code be to add into the lines above?

Any help would be appreciated. There are other "items" in the grid but I have shown only one line of code to keep it simple.

Comment: I did attempt to solve this and have looked through Google for over a week to find an answer - unsuccessfully. None of the code methods I saw addressed this particular question clearly.

Comment: So you need to show us what you tried.

Comment: Note that CSS cannot change HTML. The second image needs to be there already. Otherwise you need javascript.

Comment: So this is the code I currently have on the page: https://mediastreams.ca/grid/ :

Comment: I am unable to post the full code in this comment box (its too many characters) - is there any way I can post the full text of my answer?

Comment: I also tried this pasted inline code into each "Item" in my grid, (using the correct images of course) but it did not work:
<style>
    .card {
        width: 130px;
        height: 195px;
        background: url("/examples/images/card-back.jpg") no-repeat;
        margin: 50px;
    }
    .card:hover {
        background: url("/examples/images/card-front.jpg") no-repeat;
    }
</style>
---

Comment: Edit the question to include any necessary additional information.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a [css-grid](/questions/tagged/css-grid) question, as most of the solutions would be completely independent of the layout.

But @Paulie_D is right - CSS can't change the html code. You'd either need the image already on the page, or use javascript to swap in the src of the new image. Or use `background-image` properties on the `a` element instead of using `img` elements.

But just adding the 'on-hover' `img` to the grid (immediately alongside the 'non-hover' `img`) and hiding / unhiding with css is probably the easiest, fastest solution:

```html
<a href="/">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/b4c833/000000?text=Image+1" class="img1"/>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/000000/b4c833?text=Image+2" class="img2"/>
</a>
<style>
img {
  display: block;
}
img + img {
  display: none;
}
a:hover img {
  display: none;      
}
a:hover img + img {
  display: block;      
}
</style>
```

I'm using broad selectors here... You'd probably want to be more specific. Assuming the same code structure from the example you provided, this should be sufficient:

```
    .grid-1 img {
      display: block;
    }
    .grid-1 img + img {
      display: none;
    }
    .grid-1 a:hover img {
      display: none;      
    }
    .grid-1 a:hover img + img {
      display: block;
    }
```

Also, you have a typo in your question that's also present in your example code:
`grid-template-rows: auto quto auto;` should be `grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;` (note the second **auto**)

Comment: Sorry guys, I guess I shouldn't have posted a grid question here - am new to this site.